# Get layout information of the view

Tags: android

I have a list view that uses different layout sheets for different rows. Each sheet has different variables on them. So, when I want to implement the click listener for my list I need to know which type of row I am clicking on so that I can try to access to the correct values. For example:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

                   //do this for layout A
                   //......

                   // do that for layout B
                   //......

                   }
});
```

How can I access to the layout information and the corresponding values ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a variable in your activity where you've kept the data with which you've populated the adapter.

Then, based on the `position` variable, you'll be able to get the exact row which was clicked. Then based on the row, you'll be able to figure out what type of row it is, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method: 
public abstract int getItemViewType (int position) of your custom adapter.